# Activity from onclick menu item in Android

Tags: android-intent

How to reach from menu item to an activity in android ? I have one activity called homepage and I have created one menu with new and open menu items. When I am clicking the new menu item, it will show another activity. This is my requirement.

Comment: Have you tried anything other than asking here? Perhaps searching on a site such as [AltaVista](http://google.com) or [Lycos](http://ddg.gg)?

Comment: These are all search engines. Right ??

Comment: Yes, so you should use one *before* asking here. Anyway, please edit your title to be clear.

Comment: I am trying that level only which I already mentioned earlier..

Comment: You appear to have put no effort into this. Show us your attempts and what you found by searching.

Answer (score 1):

when you click on menu..

Just called new intent on click event of menu...

```
Intent i=new intent(this.Yournewactivity.class);
startactivity(i);
```